# How to add two pointers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cstring

How to add `parameterB` and `pictureName`? I got an error that says: '+': cannot add two pointers.

```
  CString parameterA = _T("\"") + mycustompath + _T("identify.exe\"");  
  CString parameterB = _T(" -format \"%w\" ") + _T("\"") + mycustompath;
  CString parameterC = parameterB + pictureName + _T("\"");
```

Comment: what is the type of pictureName ?

Comment: *Why*'re you trying to add two pointers?

Comment: Ask how to achieve your goals, not how to walk what you perceive to be the first step. In your case, the step went over the precipice.

Comment: You're not trying to add two pointers. You're trying to add two strings. What is the actual question here?

Comment: This user is on the verge of being banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you replace all `_T("...")` with `CString( _T("...") )` it will work 100%

Answer (score 0):

You should make `CString`s out of all the string literals, then it should work.